# How to pass components value into a function in an another component

Tags: reactjs

Given two components, I need to pass in a parameter to a function in component A (Home) from component B (Filters)

```js
export default function Filters({filter}) {
  return (
      <>
        <CarType filter={() => filter()} type="Campervan" desc="Obytka s rozměry osobáku, se kterou dojedete všude." />
        <CarType type="Integrál" desc="Král mezi karavany. Luxus na kolech." />   
        <CarType type="Vestavba" desc="Celý byt geniálně poskládaný do dodávky." />
        <CarType type="Přívěs" desc="Tažný karavan za vaše auto. Od kapkovitých až po rodinné." />
      </>
  )
}
```

```js
const Home = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(Data.items)

  const filterItem = (type) => {
    const newData = Data.items.filter((newItem) => {
      return newItem.vehicleType === type
    })
    setData(newData)
  }

  return (
      <>
        <Filters filter={() => filterItem()}/>
      </>
  )
}
```

I need to pass in a different parameter, depending on the CarType (button) I click.

Comment: Just to be clear ... you want to pass a param from `filterItem` to `Filters` ... is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct

Comment: However, `filterItem` does not render `Filters` directly ... yes? Both components are rendered by `Home`. So then your challenge is how do I pass a param from component-A to component-B but component-B is NOT a child of component-A ... does that summarize your question properly?

Comment: Yeah... that's correct

Comment: Ok, that's clear. But wait ... in this particular case, from your code, it looks like you actually want to pass component-A - `filterItem` as a prop to component-b - `Filters` ... please confirm!

Comment: filterItem has a parameter "type", I need to take the props type from Component CarCard, which is rendered in component Filters and pass it as a parameter in component Home

Comment: Wow ... it's confusing what you want to achieve, maybe edit the code properly. But quick thoughts, why not move `filterItem` to be within `Filters`? Pass `data` prop to `Filters` and then your logic should be handled there.

Comment: Well, the thing is I try to rerender the data everytime I click a the CarType button, thats why I needed the filter to be on Home.